# NPM error while installing any NPM module

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm, wampserver

Hi all I am trying to install a npm module http://socket.io/.. In fact the same error I am getting while installing **any NPM** Module.

```
C:\wamp\www\nodetutorial>npm install socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\wamp\\www\\nodetutorial\\\\node.exe" "C:\\wamp\\www\\nodet
utorial\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\nodetutorial
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.23
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.17
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\nodetutorial\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I understand that I am not answering your question, but want to ask you that are you using Windows NT for node development ? If yes, then why and what stops you from Unix flavours ? Also, can you let us know your node version ?

Comment: I am new to Node.Js .My operating system is Windows 7. I have downloaded WAMPSERVER and trying to install Socket IO and getting the above error.

Comment: ok, thats fine, sorry if I sound rude. what you get by hitting this GET request `https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io` in your browser ? Also, can you make sure that WAMP is setup correctly ? have you downloaded binaries ? NPM is not straigt forward like Linux, so this may help you getting NPM work - `https://www.npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Fancy-Windows-Install`

Comment: WAMP is up and running perfect. When I am hitting a GET request on [https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io] and getting a page full of codes. How to download Binaries..

Comment: On download page - you can see second row `Windows Binary`

Comment: Wait, `https://www.npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Fancy-Windows-Install` says that, MSI contains npm, so go with first row in download page .

Comment: do you experience any problems with internet connection?  also add `-V` parameter to get more output

Comment: my internet connection is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Firewall in my Network Connection.
Due to security policy command `C:\wamp\www\nodetutorial>npm install socket.io`
was not getting any response when it was trying to

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
```

when I tried the same command at my home without any firewall it worked fine..I got no error